# how can we get the text from rad editor from client side

Tags: telerik

Hi can we Add text to Rad control  from client side using the javascript.

Is it possible to add the text to rad editor from client side.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In order to set the text of the RadEditor on the client-side you will have to use [set_html()](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/editor-set-html.html). The linked article will show you how to utilize this function. Additionally, you can find the rest of the client-side API in that same documentation section.